# Embed expression in Report Builder for control of multiple objects?

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have a status type report where I'm using multiple colors to indicate who is where.  To control the colors, I'm using a long expression that matches an ID number to an assigned color.  Then I'm repeating this over 25 times for each particular Tablix which represents a location.

What I'm wondering is:  Would it be possible to embed the expression in a textbox, and then refer to the textbox in order to control each fields' fill color?

It seems that I would need something like

=ReportItems!FillControl.Value

in the Background Color property, with FillControl.Value being something like

=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!ProviderEmpID.Value) OR (Fields!PtOrder.Value) <> "1", "Black", "White")

, but it doesn't calculate.

By doing this, then I can duplicate the location fields multiple times, and only have to update the control once when changes need to be made.

Comment: You have to use custom code to simplify and minimize the code to duplicate. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-code-to-a-report-ssrs for details how to embed custom code.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you